# Actionscript 3 - Does handling an event work separately than a function

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, events, actionscript, handler

Let's suppose I have some event handlers set, and then I have this loop which is working, if I fire the event, will the function be triggered or will it get stuck?

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without seeing actual code.

Comment: To whoever clicked "close". Don't vote to close it. Ask for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is, for the most part, single threaded. This means that it can only do one thing at once. (You can use Workers nowadays to get around that, but we'll ignore those for the sake of this answer)

So, events can only fire when there is a gap in execution. If you have a loop running, there won't be such a gap until after that loop, and any additional code, has run.

The answer to your question is it will not run until the loop has finished. And any events that are triggered during code execution are queued and fired in order as soon as a gap in execution occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you provide me with a short example on how workers would work (in the main SWF)?

Comment: @icecreamscoop Workers are very different from threads of other platforms. You should update your question with what you're actually trying to do - it's very unlikely that workers would be the answer if you start fron running a loop and raising an event.

Comment: @icecreamscoop I actually can't. I've never used Workers myself, just read up on them. They have a similar result to threads on other platforms, but if I recall correctly behave quite different and have different purposes.

Comment: Basically I am connecting to a socket server and using a while loop to receive data from the server, while I also need to send data separately to the same server when an event is triggered.

Comment: @icecreamscoop Please update your question with that information and with the code you're using. It's not possible to answer without those.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dispatching events within your loop then your application will respond to them.

If you have a loop that is doing it's own thing and your code that dispatches events is outside of that then your application will not get those events while the loop is occurring.

In the following examples, events will be dispatched:

```
for (var i:int;i<1000;i++) {
    // do something
    dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}
```

...events will not be dispatched:

```
for (var i:int;i<1000;i++) {
    // do something
    // no events dispatched while in this loop
} 

dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

If you are in the for loop too long, AIR or the Flash Player runtime will [timeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/errors/ScriptTimeoutError.html).

Possibly a better approach would be to use a ActionScript worker as the other poster posted or check the time you've been in the loop and break out of it after a specific amount of time. You would then be breaking your work up into chunks.

```
var landBeforeTime = getTimer();

for (var i:int;i<1000;i++) {
    // do something
    // check we aren't taking too long
    if (getTimer()-landBeforeTime>1000){
       notDone = true;
       break;
    }
} 

if (notDone) {
     // come back in the next frame and finish this loop
     setTimeout (myForLoop, 100);
}
```

The previous code is an example. You'll want to use enterFrame and tidy things up.